# Sublime 3 LaTeXTools tries to invoke texify despite TexLive distribution

Tags: latexmk, sublime-text, distributions, latextools, texify

I am using Sublime 3, the LaTeXTools package, and the TexLive distribution. When I try to compile a PDF, I receive an error

```
TraditionalBuilder: Engine: pdflatex. Invoking texify...

COULD NOT COMPILE!
```

From the LaTeXTool [documentation](https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I understand that the builder should try to invoke `Latexmk` instead of `texify`. Is this the issue? Why does it not happen?

This is the result of my LaTeXTools system check:
[image]

Comment: I should mention that LaTeXTools (or rather, any LaTeX plugin for ST3) are out of date/not maintained actively/have poor support on issues. It might be worth looking into other tools which have high activity around. Take a look at the dates in the  [repo](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) to see what I mean. During my testing, I found a lot of features to be outright broken.

Comment: IIRC `Ctrl + Shift + B` helps to switch the build variant. Have you tried that to see if you can change the build system ?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it after installing Miktex

Comment: I don't think, that this really answers a question about using LaTeXTools *with TeX Live* …